# Does FindInMap work inside Fn::If with array choices?

Tags: amazon-web-services, if-statement, aws-cloudformation

We have this CFT template.

The mapping for non-prod doesn't exist hence the `If` condition. However when we apply the script, if `condIsProd` evaluates to false, the FindInMap function still evaluates and it crashes `CreateChangeSet` process.

```
SecurityGroupEgress:
        Fn::If:
          - condIsProd
          - - IpProtocol: tcp
              FromPort: !FindInMap [ mapSplunkEndpoints, !Ref paramEnvironmentType, port1 ]
              ToPort: !FindInMap [ mapSplunkEndpoints, !Ref paramEnvironmentType, port1 ]
              CidrIp: !Join ["/", [ !FindInMap [ mapSplunkEndpoints, !Ref paramEnvironmentType, port1 ], "32"]]
          - - IpProtocol: tcp
              FromPort: !FindInMap [ mapSplunkEndpoints, !Ref paramEnvironmentType, port2 ]
              ToPort: !FindInMap [ mapSplunkEndpoints, !Ref paramEnvironmentType, port2 ]
              CidrIp: !Join ["/", [ !FindInMap [ mapSplunkEndpoints, !Ref paramEnvironmentType, port2 ], "32"]]
```

This doesn't make sense because the condition is false, so why evaluates nested functions anyways.

Is there any way to prevent `FindInMap` from evaluating if the condition is false?

Comment: Can you provide your mappings and params that you use here?

Comment: Sorry I can't. You can see the mapping and param in the code above. I have checked and I know it's correct.

Comment: Did it work for you ? I am facing the same problem